# C# Remove the escape character

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, escaping

I've came across a problem with creating Facebook campaigns from .net code. The campaign name has a limit of 100 characters. When I try to submit a name that is exactly 100 chars long but with a double quote like:

```
var name = "avery\"ongnamewithalotoflettersandcharacterswhoknowswhyaverylongnamewithalotoflettersandcharacterswho";
```

.net counts the string length as 100 but FB as 101, counting the \ as extra character and fails the validation.

Wonder if there is a way to remove the \ before submission to FB?

If I split the string into code array @ http://jdstiles.com/java/cct.html

it shows code 92 for the escape slash but I'm unable to do the same in C#

Any ideas?

Comment: Facebook cannot count your string as 101 characters because `\"` is only one char. Your IDE uses two signs in order to make it easier to work with, but it's physically written as 1 character.

Answer (score 1):

For `string` in .NET, `\` and `"` are not separate characters. `\"` is an [escape sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) and it counts as one character.

As far as I aware, that's not possible.

You can't use `"` in your string without `\` except *[verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)*. Even if you delete your `\` in your string, as far as I know, there is no way to change your string from *regular string literal* to *verbatim string literal*.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var name = @"c:\all\Special\Chars\Are\Escaped";
```

or

Insert the char in manually

```
var name = "firstPart" + char(90) + "secondPart";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the FB counts the termination \0 as the additional character. Then you can effectively have only 99 visible characters and nothing you can do about it, sorry.